# PHP check for instance of DateTime?

Tags: php, class, instance, instanceof, isinstance

Is this the only way to check if an object is an instance of a class, in my case of the DateTime class?

```
$cls = ReflectionClass("DateTime");
if (! $cls->isInstance( (object) $var ) ) {
    // is not an instance
}
```

It seems a bit heavy to me.

Comment: See as well: [How to know what class is an object instance of? (php5)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1928491/how-to-know-what-class-is-an-object-instance-of-php5) (Not really a duplicate)

Answer (score 161, accepted):

You could try [`instanceof`<sup>*­Docs*</sup>](http://php.net/instanceof)...

```
if ($var instanceof DateTime) {
  // true
}
```

See also [`is_a`<sup>*­Docs*</sup>](http://php.net/is_a):

```
if (is_a($var, 'DateTime')) {
  // true
}
```

Comment: Man, I didn't find anything about that one with google .. :/ Thank you!

Answer (score 10):

`if ($var instanceof DateTime)`

Answer (score 7):

You can use get_class function like this:

```
<?php

    $a = new DateTime();
    if (get_class($a) == 'DateTime') {
        echo "Datetime";
    }
```

Comment: @redolent If you are using Symfony or some other framework that uses namespaces, you may need to declare `use \DateTime` at the top of your file to make it look for `DateTime` in the root namespace (not your app's namespace).

Answer (score 5):

What about [instanceof](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.type.php)