# Magento - how to determine if an object is a Varien object?

Tags: php, magento, object, magento-1.7

I want a simple snippet which will look at an object and determine if this is a valid Varien object (rather than a standard PHP object).

eg.

```
 if ( this is a varien_object )
     do this..
 else
     do something else
```

Comment: http://php.net/instanceof - please use the search and the manual.

Comment: Just for wording clarification: The Varien object is a standard PHP object, just a more specific one.

Comment: Perhaps better dupe: [PHP check for instance of DateTime?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9568793/php-check-for-instance-of-datetime)

Comment: no need, maximum all the ojects are varien objects for all models

Answer (score 5):

use PHP [instanceof](http://www.php.net/manual/en/internals2.opcodes.instanceof.php) operator

```
if ($this instanceof Varien_Object )
 do this..
```

Comment: thanks - simple i was thinking it was something odd to Magento